# How do plot f(x) = e^x - 4x^3 + 1 in Python with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is my code which I use to draw this function with matplotlib:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-2,2,1000)
fx = []
for i in range (len(x)):
    fx.append(math.exp(x[i]) - 4*x[i]**3 + 1)
    # print(math.exp(x[i]) - 4*x[i]**3 + 1)
plt.plot(x, fx)
plt.grid()
plt.axvline()
plt.axhline()
plt.show()
```

Following shows the result of my code next to the expected graph:
[image: Figure 1 is my code result and the other are the actual graph]

Comment: They're the same graph with different axes labels. Use `plt.xticks` and `plt.yticks` to make them look the same.

Comment: So what is your question?  Those seem to be the same graph, just with rather different axis ranges.

Comment: Please note that when using numpy you don't need (or want) to fill the data using a for loop.  Instead use fx = np.exp(x) + 4.0*np.power(x,3) + 1  Waay more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's plotted correctly just that the plot you got and the graph from the image are on different scales. You can try multiplying the scale factor by say 5 to get a similar result to the image.

```py
multiplier = 5

xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
ymin, ymax = plt.ylim()

plt.xlim(xmin * multiplier, xmax * multiplier)
plt.ylim(ymin * multiplier, ymax * multiplier)
```